# check if aio_write finished

Tags: c, unix, synchronization, aio

Is there any way to check if there are no AIO writes to a given file? Im making an project on my Unix course which will be a context free (based on UDP) chess server and all data has to be stored in files. Application will be single proccess and single threaded (expect for AIO functions). My problem is that:

1)Player One sends some data which triggers aio_write operation to files and the process goes 
2)Player Two requests current board state which should be read from that file, but if previous aio_write hasnt finished yet then this file is not final and so I should not read yet but wait for aio_write to end. 
Problem is that as it is context free I dont have aiocb structure from aio_write call.

Also there could be aio_writes from other games (which use diffrent files) on which I dont need to care, only if specific file is currently on write.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using AIO for this? The purpose of AIO is not synchronization between processes. It's purely to prevent your process from sleeping in kernelspace when a read or write can't be satisfied immediately due to disk load (reading) or cache pressure (writing). On such small transactions as a chess game will be working with, AIO should behave exactly the same as normal `read` and `write` IO: all operations will complete immediately, albeit with moderately more overhead.

If your goal is to synchronize file access, you could perhaps use `fcntl` locking, or `mmap` your files and include a mutex or semaphore somewhere in the file.

Comment: I'd like to add that, as usual, NFS is Weird, and you can't rely on synchronisation to work properly with it. (Although I think it's OK if both processes are on the same machine.)

Comment: As I wrote is for UNIX Course and one of the requirements is to use Asynchronous Input-Output only :/

Comment: *Sigh*... Why are instructors teaching the most horribly misdesigned and useless interface in POSIX? I don't think AIO can help you achieve the synchronization you need, as it is not a synchronization method...

Comment: After spending more time on lecture notes and other I think that the way to acomplish it should be file locks...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's context-free shouldn't stop you from keeping some state information.

You could keep the context (I mean the **`io_context`**) and just reuse it (send a read request and wait for it - **`io_getevents`**). [`io_submit`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/io_submit.2.html) says it pushes requests in a queue so I believe it will preserve the order of operations.

Alternatively, (if you find out that `io_submit` doesn't preserve the order) you could keep enough state to know that a write operation is pending and wait using `io_getevents`. *Then* reading will be safe.

I hope I didn't misread your question.

**EDIT**

**It seems I *did* misread your question**. You are likely talking about POSIX `aio(7)`. I was talking about true asynchronous I/O (`libaio.h`). POSIX aio is usually implemented using threads (which kind of sucks).

Either way, if you can wait for events (which I think you can) you can still do it: keep some state to declare a write is pending, and when someone wants to read wait for the write to complete.

Comment: You can wait for your own events, but I don't know any way to wait for an event triggered by another application. Pretty much all POSIX AIO does, conceptually, is a blocking read or write in a new thread with a notification signal or callback when it finishes... with a horribly ugly API. This is not a primitive that can be used to build inter-process synchronization.

Comment: @R.. I think he's using the same process - a server that receives UDP messages from clients.

Comment: OK I think I get it. The server is just using AIO waits to synchronize with itself. In reality, all AIO ops will take place immediately and waits will all immediately return. This is a really useless exercise...